# Creating empty files in new location

Tags: macos, bash, find

I have a directory full of files. The tree looks something like this:

```
|-- test1a
|   |-- test1b
|       |-- foo.txt
|       |-- bar.txt
|-- test2a
|   |-- test2b
```

Where the directory names match the regular expression `test[1-9][ab]`.

---

Using `find` in bash, I'm trying to create blank files in `test2b` with the same filenames and extensions as those in `test1b`.

So far, I've tried the following:

```
find test1a/test1b -type f -exec touch test2a/test2b {} \;
```

This, however, does not work. I don't have much experience with bash, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem using the following:

```
$ cd test2a/test2b
$ find ../../test1a/test1b -type f -exec sh -c 'touch $(basename {})' \;
```

---

I believe the problem was resulting from `{}` giving the full path rather than the filename. It was then trying to create a file that already existed, so it left it alone and did nothing.

Comment: There is a problem, if there is a filepath like this: `test1a/test1b/some-dir/some-file`. It will create `test2a/test2b/some-file`

Comment: This could however, work... `cd test1a/test1b; find . -type d -exec mkdir -p '../../test2a/test2b/{}'; find . -type f -exec touch '../../test2a/test2b/{}'; `

Answer (score 0):

Here is a second approach:

```
find test1a/test1b -type f -execdir echo touch test2a/test2b/{} \; > adhoc.sh
sh adhoc.sh
```